# Why i can not read JSON from this URL?

Tags: android, json

I faced a problem that I couldn't read the content of a JSON file, the code as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LoadJsonAsync().execute("http://dongabank.com.vn/exchange/export");
            }
        });
    }

    class LoadJsonAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            if(params[0] != null){
                return readFromURL(params[0]);
            }else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private static String readFromURL(String url){
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            URLConnection urlConnection = u.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                content.append(line + "\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content.toString();
    }

}
```

The problem is [from](http://dongabank.com.vn/exchange/export)

When i try to use other `json` links, it work properly. But when i use `json` link above, i couldn't read anything from this. 
Is anyone explain to me the reason why? and how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's becouse this JSON response is not JSON.

Aparently this JSON response is wrapped in brackets. You have to retrieve the response as String an then remove the first and the last bracket before parse as JSON.

Comment: To remove brackets is simple for me. But why I can't read into bufferedReader?

Comment: After a test I figured out that for some reason this server respond with error if you don't specify "Accept" header.
Add this line `urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");` after open the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not valid, remove the bracket at the beginning and the end of your string

Answer (score -1):

It's not a JSON, It's like a JSONP, Google it